# Prevent updates to unaltered items in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list constructed using `ng-repeat`; the list contains sliders relevant to each individual item. Changing a single item causes the whole list to re-render. How can I prevent unchanged items from re-rendering?

```
<ul ng-repeat="obj in collection">
  <li class="obj">
    {{obj}}
    <input type="range" ng-model = "obj.value">
  </li>
</ul>
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/vumeyawomo/edit?html,js,output)

(In the actual project I am working on, re-rendering the entire list is costly because there are a lot of MathQuill expressions. Also, the slider is animated so re-renders would happen a lot.)

Comment: I am not sure if thats possible in AngularJS but what i understand is AngularJS uses dirty checking for updating the values. Even if we change one value inside an array or an object, the whole digest  cycle would be called so that it will be updated in the view also.

Comment: Is it a problem that they are re-rendering? If so, why?

Comment: How do you think it is re-rendering ?

Comment: in your jsbin example, each list item is dirty, so a re-render has to be done by angular.

Comment: @JLRishe It's a problem because in my real application, the re-rendering is slow due to a bunch of math expressions (mathquill; like mathias but more easily editable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
FYI the list is not re-rendering even if you add content to it.
You can check the same by opening developer tools.
I've added data attribute to each `li` so that you can easily check that the list is not re-rendering.
For performance improvements you can use track by expression like below

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="obj in collection track by obj.name" class="obj" data-name="{{obj.name}}">
    {{obj}}
    <input type="range" ng-model = "obj.value">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Updated [jsinb](http://jsbin.com/zusofiv/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks! You helped me realize my problem was not what I thought. In my real code I had some JS that *was* adding new elements each time—fixed.